# Can I export history of commands in git in file.txt?

Tags: git

I know how to copy the output of commands from git for example i will copy all branches that I created

```
git branch |clip
```

OR export it in a text file by this command

```
git branch > branch.txt
```

But the question can i copy all commands that I write it in a text file like matlab and where save in windows.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? Bash or PowerShell or something else? Which version?

Comment: I am using `windows` and `bash` the version of bash is  `2.16.0.windows.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash you can use the `history` command to display a list of all the commands you executed. You can also run `history n` where n is the number of commands you want to see.

Run the following to write the history content to a text file:

```
history -w ~/history.txt
```

By doing a `grep` on history you can filter it down to the commands that use git:

```
history | grep git
```

If you want to output the grep content to a file you can run:

```
history | grep git >  ~/history.txt
```

As a side note, the following PowerShell command gets all your PowerShell history and filters it to lines starting with git:

```
Get-Content -Path (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath | Where {$_ -like 'git *'}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DOSKEY /HISTORY | clip` or `DOSKEY /HISTORY > history.txt` works for Windows Command Prompt

The first command clips the history to the clipboard while the next write out to a .txt file.